# Accordion Menu - Where is the original CSS file of the module?

Tags: navigation

I tried for two hours to *RTLize\Flip* the module via *Firebug* & *Style.css* but without major success. So I figured this is one of case when the flipping should be done at the module's CSS files themselves. So I went to `sites/all/modules/accordion_menu` but I couldn't find anything that has all the *CSS*. I found only `accordion_menu.css` that doesn't have more than 4-5 rows of *CSS* code. So it's not something I could *RTLize\flip*.

Therefore I ask, where is the genuine *Accordion Menu* CSS file (that appear in DOM but not in the style window)? How could I track it down and flip it's CSS?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand. CSS should always be overridable. Unless it's inline. But then again you can use `!important` to override inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Accordion Menu module uses jQuery UI, which is included with core. If the styles you're looking for are in a CSS file, they'll be in /misc/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.css (or possibly one of the more general jQuery UI CSS files).

Bear in mind that jQuery UI is a javascript library, so the styles might be applied directly to the elements at runtime, and may never exist in a CSS file as such.

Comment: Indeed it was at root/misc/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.css, changed it from there, and it work... Allow just to ask why is it actually in this folder? Did this module put this file there in the misc/ui folder?

Comment: No it's part of jquery UI (which is included with Drupal) the module you're using just piggy-backs off that